# How To read User Information List In SharePoint 2013 Using Power Shell Scripts

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-on-prem, user-profile-property

I want to retrieve all the user email id, display name, user name & Title from user information list using power shell

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below PowerShell script:

```
function ExtractSPuserInformationListToCSV()
{

param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SiteURL

    )

    $web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
    $list = $web.Lists["User Information List"]  

    $spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery  

    $CamlQueryString = '<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Title" Ascending="True" /></OrderBy></Query>'  

    $spQuery.Query = $CamlQueryString  

    $userInformationListItemsColls = $list.GetItems($spQuery)  

foreach($oneUserInInformationList in $userInformationListItemsColls) 
{  

    Write-Host $oneUserInInformationList.Title 


    $userData = Get-SPUser -Web $web.URL -Identity $oneUserInInformationList["ows_Name"]

    $UserInformationlistItemData = @{
    "Display Name" = $userData.DisplayName
    "User Login" = $userData.UserLogin
    "Email" = $userData.Email
    "Name" = $userData.Name

}
New-Object PSObject -Property $UserInformationlistItemData


}


$web.Dispose();  
return $UserInformationlistItemData


}


#Call the function like below

ExtractSPuserInformationListToCSV "YourSiteURL" | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "Your CSV Path";
```

Comment: Hi - if it has helped you, could you please [Upvote(^)] and mark as answered.